# dbnull exception when null value in DB

Tags: dbnull

when am getting a value and stores a value in long variable DBNULL exception occur .because that column in the table having null value how i can get that NULL value also.could anybody help me

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                long linvs = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["individualsize"]));
                long uds = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["dataspace"]));
                long avds = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["amemory"]));

                dr["individualsize"] = BytesToString(linvs);
                dr["dataspace"] = BytesToString(uds);
                dr["amemory"] = BytesToString(avds);

            }
```

Comment: "individualsize" is the field name in DB which having NULL value

Comment: Your question makes no sense, like I don't understand what your trying to say

Comment: "individualsize" dataspace,amemory are the field name in DB which having NULL value and i need to display all the value in gridview but "invalidcastexception was unhandled by user code" this exception is occuring

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to check the result of that variable for DBNULL and if it is that, then set your variable to NULL.

Although you cannot assign longs as null... Unless you made it the Java class Long before you set it.

Hope that helps out some....

Comment: Some candidate having value for that field and some are not. i need to get all the value even in null

Comment: I'm confused... So you can't check for DBNULL as you look them up? Then set your variable to null if it is?

Comment: am a fresher working in a existing project . am little bit cant understand the coding IN DB those fields datatypes are Varchar . in this page they are showing that table but "invalidcastexception was unhandled by user code" is occuring when am checking with break point at the line               " long linvs = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["individualsize"]));"

Comment: also i cant check,value in that fields are null

Comment: how to Convert null field to zero before converting to long